# Open website with Trident web engine in android

Tags: android, trident

Is there any way to load a web page with `Trident` web engine (windows IE engine) in android.
as you know in android website decode with `webkit` engine.

Comment: Dare I ask why you want to do this?

Comment: @TrevorD There is website open just with `Trident` engine and i need show this website in something like `webview`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Android is written on Linux, which cannot run win32 programs natively.

Trident barely ran on different versions of Windows.